# competing consumer groups on a partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have certain type of messages which take a long time to process - 5% of population.
However, it is not possible to identify the message till it is actually picked up for processing by the consumer.

The objective is to clear-off/repost the subsequent messages to other partitions - the moment a 'slow' message is identified.

In this context, is it possible for a partition to be listened to by two consumer groups - a processor and a router.
The router front runs the processor on the partition - and clears the partition if it comes to know that the processor of that partition is ingesting a slow message at the moment(through a state flag).
ie Can a consumer group front run another on the same partition - and alter contents of the partition ,before the other one reaches the offset.

Comment: why you want to move to different partition of the same topic? why cant you use another topic to hold the long running ones? If you are using streams api (not sure on consumer api), you can easily right an if-else logic. If type=long run then publish to another topic else continue processing. Its not a good idea to use another partition of same topic since partitions can be dynamically allocated to another instance of the same consumer group due to rebalance.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood last part of the post. You cannot alter/clear offsets in a partition (records are immutable). You can have  many consumer groups reading from a topic (they don't compete), but they won't share offsets and you won't be able to commit between those groups unless you manage offset storage and consumer seeking manually, yourself